# Replace foreach loop with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I tried to replace code

```
foreach (var discovery in mpwrapper.parser.Discoveries)
{
   solution.AddFile("Discoveries", discovery.DisplayStringName + ".mpx", discovery);
}
```

with the following linq expression

```
mpwrapper.parser.Discoveries.Select(
                    s => solution.AddFile("Discoveries", s.DisplayStringName + ".mpx", s));
```

But got an error

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments explicitly.

How to convert this foreach loop to linq query where I execute a method on each object in my IEnumerable collection?

Comment: I'm guessing that your `solution.AddFile` method doesn't return anything - would that be correct?

Comment: `Select` to execute code with side effects is improper use. Just do the `foreach`. Or `List<T>.ForEach()` which is a method that is expected to have side effects (= state changes outside the method).

Comment: As an aside, changing `foreach` loops to Linq just for the sake of it is one of the most common techniques to make code harder to understand and debug that I'm aware of in .NET.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think what you need is the ForEach method ;)

```
mpwrapper.parser.Discoveries.ToList().ForEach(s => { solution.AddFile("Discoveries", s.DisplayStringName + ".mpx", s); });
```

Comment: Or just stick with `foreach`, which is clearer here IMO. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx. Note that without knowing the type of `Discoveries`, we don't know whether this will compile...

Comment: He's saying that it's an IEnumerable object, so it should compile.
I answered what he asked regardless if it's better or not. But you're right, it might be better to use foreach instead.

Comment: No, there's no `ForEach` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`. You could write one of course, but I'd advise against it.

Comment: I added the ToList() call that I had forgot ;P

Comment: will Linq foreach increase performance when compared to normal foreach on top of a list?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is Select needs to return a value, but also Linq is not designed to mutate collections. Think of select as a transformation over the collection rather than a state change for each item

Maybe a foreach loop is the best solution here

Comment: Well, LINQ works with mutable collections too - but isn't designed to mutate them itself.

Answer (score 4):

LINQ stands for Language INtegrated Query... yet you aren't actually *querying* anything.

If `mpwrapper.parser.Discoveries` is a `List<T>`, you can use the `ForEach` method; or, if it is an `IEnumerable`, you could always add a `ForEach` extension method… but this is more a minor aesthetic change and has nothing to do with LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

I use a little cheat with the .All method. It simply requires a return boolean value and presents very neatly. I included a sample with embeded linq inside the .All

```
configurations.All(c =>
{
    var gcx = globalConfigurations.FirstOrDefault(gc =>
        gc.Type == c.Type && configurationGuids.Any(cGuid => gc.Guid == cGuid)
    );
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `List<T>.ForEach` method does the trick.

However, this method does not exist on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mpwrapper.parser.Discoveries.ToList()
    .ForEach(s =>
        solution.AddFile("Discoveries", s.DisplayStringName + ".mpx", s));
```

Answer (score 0):

If Discoveries is a list, then do it like this

```
mpwrapper.parser.Discoveries.ForEach(discovery => solution.AddFile("Discoveries", discovery .DisplayStringName + ".mpx", discovery);
```

If not, convert it to List first :)