# Replacing foreach on a list with LINQ

Tags: linq

I'm not sure if this would be desirable, but is there a LINQ "way" of replacing the following:

```
foreach (var u in users)
    context.Users.Add(u);
```

with something like

context.Users.Add(....);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace foreach loop with linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572213/replace-foreach-loop-with-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `users` is type `List<User>` you just do

```
users.ForEach(u => context.Users.Add(u));
```

though you don't need to use LINQ. You could just do

```
context.Users.AddRange(users);
```

Comment: `ForEach` is not LINQ. It's just a method on `List<T>`.

Comment: Totally forgot about AddRange, but also forgot about ForEach methods being available on List<T>.  Anything that let's me make 3 lines of code into one, yet still readable is a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need LINQ. You need to use [`AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt136629(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbSet%601.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7B%600%7D)) instead of `Add`:

```
context.Users.AddRange(users);
```

*Assumption: you're using Entity Framework and `Users` is of type `DbSet<T>`*

Answer (score 0):

If `Users` is a `DbSet` then you can probably do without looping at all by using [`AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
context.Users.AddRange(users);
```

However if you really want to use Linq, then you can also do this:

```
users.ToList().ForEach(u => context.Users.Add(u));
```

Or the shorthand version:

```
users.ToList().ForEach(context.Users.Add);
```